# Spring MVC: Securing handler method

Tags: security, spring-mvc, controller, spring-security

I'm wondering what is good approach to secure `handler method` in Spring MVC controller. Now i use `@Secured` annotation, that ensure that some method may be accessed by logged user only. But how to ensure that one logged user doesn't do something bad for other users ? For example i have method that delete item with given `id`. To ensure that someone can't remove other than his items i check item owner. Is better way to do something like that ?

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@RequestMapping("/deleteitem.html")
public String delete(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
    Item b = itemDAO.get(id);
    if(b.getOwner().getId().equals(((UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser().getId())) {
        itemDAO.delete(id);
    }
    return "redirect:/user/items.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can look at [@Preauthorize](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations) annotation.  You can do something like

```
@PreAuthorize("#item.id == authentication.id")
  public void doSomething(Item item);
```

You would need to rewrite your current code suitably.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Spring Security ACL (Access control list) you can create a list of permissions that users have for this object.  Permissions include read, write, delete...

Comment: I don't want to restrict some actions to specific users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement role base system, base on privileges user can perform delete operation.

If specific user having delete access then he/she do the delete stub.